# Studio HTTP Request

Tags: twilio-studio

I am dealing with Studio I am using an HTTP Request, which brings me the following information.

```
[
    {
        "id": 131316,
        "name": "User 1",
        "location_id": 38716,
        "times": [
            {
                "day": 1,
                "day_name": "Monday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 1,
                "day_name": " Monday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 2,
                "day_name": "Tuesday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 2,
                "day_name": "Tuesday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 3,
                "day_name": "Wednesday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 3,
                "day_name": "Wednesday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 4,
                "day_name": "Thursday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 4,
                "day_name": "Thursday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 5,
                "day_name": "Friday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 5,
                "day_name": "Friday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "17:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 131313,
        "name": "User 2",
        "location_id": 38716,
        "times": [
            {
                "day": 1,
                "day_name": " Monday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "14:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 1,
                "day_name": " Monday",
                "open": "15:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 2,
                "day_name": "Tuesday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "14:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 2,
                "day_name": "Tuesday",
                "open": "15:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 3,
                "day_name": "Wednesday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "14:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 3,
                "day_name": "Wednesday",
                "open": "15:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 4,
                "day_name": "Thursday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "14:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 4,
                "day_name": "Thursday",
                "open": "15:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 5,
                "day_name": "Friday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "14:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 5,
                "day_name": "Friday",
                "open": "15:00",
                "close": "17:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 130975,
        "name": "User 3",
        "location_id": 38716,
        "times": [
            {
                "day": 1,
                "day_name": " Monday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 1,
                "day_name": " Monday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 2,
                "day_name": "Tuesday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 2,
                "day_name": "Tuesday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 3,
                "day_name": "Wednesday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 3,
                "day_name": "Wednesday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 4,
                "day_name": "Thursday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 4,
                "day_name": "Thursday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "18:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 5,
                "day_name": "Friday",
                "open": "08:30",
                "close": "13:00"
            },
            {
                "day": 5,
                "day_name": "Friday",
                "open": "14:00",
                "close": "17:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to capture the "name" information that comes from the HTTP response but I have not been able to do it. I have used the following options without it working for me.

```
{{widgets.ListaPrestadores.response.parsed.name}}
{{widgets.ListaPrestadores.response.parsed.name[0]}}
{{widgets.ListaPrestadores.response.body.parsed.name}}
{{widgets.ListaPrestadores.response.body.parsed.name[0]}}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that if you return a JSON response to the HTTP request widget that is an array, [it won't parse the result](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request#returning-json).

You will need to return a plain object, perhaps by proxying the request via a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) to extract the data that you need.